# Insert data using joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where the segment field was filled incorrectly as 'None', how can I do without an update and insert data from the same table with correctly filled segments using joins?

Can match using unique fields phone_number, name, patronym.
It is also necessary that the date of one client must be the largest, so that the chance of filling the segment correctly is greater.

Example of table:

| summ | phone | name | patronym | DATE | STATUS | SEGMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12654 | 8706124512 | Steve | Alikhanov | 20.07.2022 | DONE | None |
| 12654 | 8706124512 | Steve | Alikhanov | 10.06.2022 | IN PROCESS | 1-2 NB |
| 52165 | 8706124512 | Steve | Alikhanov | 09.01.2021 | NOT DONE | 2-3 NB |

According to my junior thinking, need to create 2 identical tables, where in the first one there will be all data with an incorrectly filled field, and in the second all unique values ​​with a correctly filled segment field.
From the main table, delete all data with an incorrectly filled segment and, using the joins of two test tables, insert the already corrected version of the data.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an `UPDATE` to do this work?

Comment: @Boneist idk, but my update or merge scripts don't work

Comment: "I can't get my update or merge statements to work" isn't really a valid reason to say "I don't want to use an update, I want to do at least twice as much work to achieve the same result", though. Perhaps you should update your question to add in what you've tried and explain how it "didn't work", and we may be able to help you get the update/merge statement to work.

Comment: @Boneist update works much longer, it would be more efficient to insert ready-made data

Comment: Sure, but you're not just inserting ready-made data - you're proposing to find the incorrect rows, delete them, then find the correct rows and insert them back into the table... you don't think that's going to be at least as slow, if not way slower than doing an update?

You may find it quicker to create a table that's the copy of the original table but with the corrected rows in it, truncate the original table and then insert all rows back in, but given we know nothing about your tables (sizes, indexex, any fkeys linked to this table, etc), it's difficult to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these query below (I suppose than the key of segment are "summ" field):

```
--  Record to Insert
    insert into mytable
    with mytable     as (
                         select 12654 as summ, 8706124512 as phone, 'Steve' as name, 'Alikhanov' as patronym, '20.07.2022' as DATE1, 'DONE'       as STATUS, 'None'   as SEGMENT from dual union all
                         select 12654 as summ, 8706124512 as phone, 'Steve' as name, 'Alikhanov' as patronym, '10.06.2022' as DATE1, 'IN PROCESS' as STATUS, '1-2 NB' as SEGMENT from dual union all
                         select 52165 as summ, 8706124512 as phone, 'Steve' as name, 'Alikhanov' as patronym, '09.01.2021' as DATE1, 'NOT DONE'   as STATUS, '2-3 NB' as SEGMENT from dual
                        ),
        test_table_1 as (
                         --the first one there will be all data with an incorrectly filled field 
                         select summ, phone, name, patronym, date1, status, segment
                           from mytable
                          where segment = 'None'        
                        ),
        test_table_2 as (
                         --the second all unique values ​​with a correctly filled segment field 
                         select summ, phone, name, patronym, max(date1), status, segment
                           from mytable test_table2
                          where segment <> 'None'
                          group by summ, phone, name, patronym, status, segment
                        )   
         select test_table_1.summ, test_table_1.phone, test_table_1.name, test_table_1.patronym, test_table_1.date1, test_table_2.status, test_table_2.segment
           from test_table_1, 
                test_table_2
          where test_table_1.summ     = test_table_2.summ
            and test_table_1.phone    = test_table_2.phone
            and test_table_1.name     = test_table_2.name
            and test_table_1.patronym = test_table_2.patronym;
                
                
      SUMM      PHONE NAME  PATRONYM  DATE1      STATUS     SEGMEN
---------- ---------- ----- --------- ---------- ---------- ------
     12654 8706124512 Steve Alikhanov 20.07.2022 IN PROCESS 1-2 NB
                

--  Record to delete
    delete from mytable 
     where segment = 'None'
      with mytable as (
                       select 12654 as summ, 8706124512 as phone, 'Steve' as name, 'Alikhanov' as patronym, '20.07.2022' as DATE1, 'DONE'       as STATUS, 'None'   as SEGMENT from dual union all
                       select 12654 as summ, 8706124512 as phone, 'Steve' as name, 'Alikhanov' as patronym, '10.06.2022' as DATE1, 'IN PROCESS' as STATUS, '1-2 NB' as SEGMENT from dual union all
                       select 52165 as summ, 8706124512 as phone, 'Steve' as name, 'Alikhanov' as patronym, '09.01.2021' as DATE1, 'NOT DONE'   as STATUS, '2-3 NB' as SEGMENT from dual
                      );
```

I hope that I understand your problem. In case negative please specify me better the output of record that you should to insert.

Thank you

Comment: In the myTable, I will have to add all the data for each user?

Comment: I have about 360k of data there that are incorrectly filled in the segment field

Comment: No, mytable is just your table that contain 360k. I have simulate it with clause "With" to try the query. Then you can create test_table1 and test_table2 with CREATE standard clause. The quey to run will be "insert into mytable select test_table_1.summ, test_table_1 ....."

Comment: Do you know how to delete all duplicates and leave data with unique number and maximum date? Cause I can use left join and just insert data with fixed segment without any updating

Comment: Yes, I add the query to next answer here below

Answer (score 1):

I answer about previous comment:

```
delete from mytable d 
 where d.summ in (
                  -- have two or more duplicate rows (summ is primary keys)
                  select b.summ
                    from mytable b
                   group by b.summ
                   having count(*) >= 2
                 )
   and d.rowid not in (
                       -- list rowid of rows to not delete (unique number with maximum date1)
                       select x.codrowid
                         from (
                               -- extract the first rowid that having maximum date1 
                               select min(rowid), a.summ, max(date1) 
                                 from mytable a
                                where a.summ in (
                                                 -- have two or more duplicate rows (summ is primary keys)
                                                 select b.summ
                                                   from mytable b
                                                  group by b.summ
                                                 having count(*) >= 2
                                                )
                                group by a.summ
                               ) x
                      );
```

In case of more duplicates rows with same date1, query takes the first founded.

Thank you.